# Why tensorboard does not find my keras events?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, tensorboard

I'm using keras with the tensoflow backend on windows, and I want to do visualizations with tensorboard. The problem I have is that in the folder I see the files created by keras, but when you want to view them in tensorboard, it does not find them

```
callbacks = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='C:\\Users\\pc1\\Desktop\\logs\\', histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True, write_images=True, embeddings_freq=1)

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=50, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
   model.fit(X_train, y_train, callbacks = [callbacks])
```

Check the directory:`C:\Users\pc1\Desktop\logs>dir`

`10/06/2017  13:43         1.351.108 events.out.tfevents.1497094943.DESKTOP-05415FP
 10/06/2017  13:54         1.481.044 events.out.tfevents.1497095663.DESKTOP-05415FP`

```
C:\>tensorboard --inspect --logdir='C:\Users\pc1\Desktop\logs\'
```

No event files found within logdir 'C:\Users\pc1\Desktop\logs\'

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove that last slash/backslash from your Tensorboard inspect: `tensorboard --inspect --logdir='C:\Users\pc1\Desktop\logs'`.

In general your eventfiles need to be inside a folder thats inside the logdir you point Tensorboard to.

I usually use this snippet:

```
now = datetime.now()
logdir = "_tf_logs/" + now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + "/"
tb = TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
callbacks=[tb]
…
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 16, epochs = 4, 
     verbose = 0, callbacks = callbacks)
```

Being within the directory that has _tf_logs in it I initiate Tensorboard with:

```
tensorboard --logdir=_tf_logs
```

Comment: Same result, No event files found within logdir